# ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI is showing deprecated in code.I had use Network Capabilities in above M version , want to remove warning of deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-connectivitymanager

I want to remove the warning which is showing in the code below m version.I had use below code which is working good but still want to remove the warning which is showing in line ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI.Can below warning be removed which is also showing in kotlin compiler ??

```
val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm?.run {
                cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                    if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                        return true
                    } else if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            cm?.run {
                cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        return true
                    } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Warning :- 'getter for type: Int' is deprecated.

Comment: TL;DR: I don't think you can. 

Lint currently doesn't check for deprecated code (only deprecated xml attributes&libraries: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+log/studio-master-dev/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks) so deprecation is checked by Java/Kotlin compiler by looking for 
 @Deprecated annotations.

What you need is a check that knows this is a code path for a specific Android version (< M), look into the SDK of that Android version (M) to see if it's deprecated and only then flag it. Would make sense to file a Lint issue imho.

Comment: Yes , i want to change else condition code for version < M and >16 so that warning can be removed and i can check network condition without deprecation warning on 29 version.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816443/what-is-alternative-to-connectivitymanager-type-wifi-deprecated-in-android-p-api

Comment: I had checked this link before.Please double check the code before commenting it is duplicate.I want to support all version not only above M version which NetworkCapabilities support.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

You can use **`@Suppress("DEPRECATION")`** to remove that warning

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class Main2Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2)

        val networkResult = getConnectionType(this)

    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    fun getConnectionType(context: Context): Boolean {
        var result = false
        val cm = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager?
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            cm?.run {
                cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.activeNetwork)?.run {
                    if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                        result = true
                    } else if (hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                        result = true
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            cm?.run {
                cm.activeNetworkInfo?.run {
                    if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        result = true
                    } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        result = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

**CHECK THE SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Comment: I don't want to use @Suppress("DEPRECATION").This is not the correct way to do it.I want to change in code or to replace the code so that the warning automatically gone without using deprecation code .

Comment: @AnkitGupta actually using `@Suppress("DEPRECATION")` is the correct way to handle this. The deprecation is a warning and as long as you support versions having this API and compiling with versions providing the signature, everything is good. If your minimal SDK is set to 21, you could also only use the if-branch, as it was introduced in Android L.