# How to know the internet connection type that my mobile uses

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, android-connectivitymanager

I want to know the type of internet connection my mobile uses (Cellular or wifi).

```
Network network;  
manager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (manager != null){
if (manager.getNetworkCapabilities(network).hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)){
Toast.makeText(this, "Mobile Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     }
```

An error message says:

> (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'booleanandroid.net.NetworkCapabilities.hasTransport(int)' on a null object reference).

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android

Comment: Some methods like(getType) have been deprecated.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547006/connectivitymanager-getnetworkinfoint-deprecated

Answer (score 3):

**try this.**

```
String networkStatus ="";
final ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
//Check Wifi
final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//Check for mobile data
final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if( wifi.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
    networkStatus = "wifi";
}else if(mobile.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
    networkStatus = "mobileData";
}else{
    networkStatus="noNetwork";
}
return networkStatus;
```

Comment: getType method has benn deprecated to networkcapabilities.

Comment: please check it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816443/what-is-alternative-to-connectivitymanager-type-wifi-deprecated-in-android-p-api

Answer (score 1):

You can check by using below code:

```
    private void checkInternetConnectionType() {
        boolean isConnected = false;
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = null;
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager)  this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm != null) {
            activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }

        boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
        boolean isMobileData = activeNetwork.getType() ==  ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
}
```

Add following permissions to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Also, check these documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring#java

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html

Answer (score 1):

Use getCurrentNetworkType function of bellow class (You can modify class and have just 1 function, this class is a part of my project):

```
public class ConnectionManagerK {

private static String TAG = "ConnectionManagerK";
private static ConnectionManagerK Instance;

public static ConnectionManagerK getInstance() {
    ConnectionManagerK localInstance = Instance;
    if (localInstance == null) {
        synchronized (ConnectionManagerK .class) {
            localInstance = Instance;
            if (localInstance == null) {
                Instance = localInstance = new ConnectionManagerK ();
            }
        }
    }
    return localInstance;
}


public static int getCurrentNetworkType() {
    if (isConnectedOrConnectingToWiFi()) {
        return StatsController.TYPE_WIFI;
    } else if (isRoaming()) {
        return StatsController.TYPE_ROAMING;
    } else {
        return StatsController.TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
}


public static boolean isNetworkOnline() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && (netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() || netInfo.isAvailable())) {
            return true;
        }
        netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FileLog.e(e);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isRoaming() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null) {
            return netInfo.isRoaming();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FileLog.e(e);
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isConnectedOrConnectingToWiFi() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo.State state = netInfo.getState();
        if (netInfo != null && (state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || state == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING || state == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED)) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FileLog.e(e);
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean isConnectedToWiFi() {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ApplicationLoader.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FileLog.e(e);
    }
    return false;
}}
```